# Improve Python iteration performance

Tags: python, performance, iteration

So I've been reading about list comprehensions, maps and generators as fast ways to iterate but all the examples are generating a new array from an existing array.

In my particular case I'd like to update the values of a region of an existing 2 dimensional array. Can someone help me understand how I can apply one of these fast iterators to my particular case?

Here's a distillation of the code in question:

```
buffer = [[0 for x in xrange(buffer_width)] for x in xrange(buffer_height)]

offset_x = 10
offset_y = 10

width = len(data)
height = len(data[0])

for x in range(0, width, 1):                                                                          
    for y in range(0, height, 1):
        bx = int(offset_x + x)
        by = int(offset_y + y)

        buffer[bx][by] = data[x][y] | buffer[bx][by]
```

Gah! Sorry for the bad code formatting; apparently posting from a mobile phone is not such a good idea

Edit: sorry for the bad initial code, I've edited it to be clearer. Hopefully it's apparent that I'm merging the values of a small 2D array into the exisiting values of a larger 2D array

Comment: as far as my understanding goes, generators do not create a new array. It generates and proceeds without remembering the previous values. It is meant for faster operations of iterables. I am not aware that they generate a new array.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Pure python**

```
for x in xrange(offset_x, width):
    for y in xrange(offset_y, height):
        data[y][x] = buffer[y-offset_y][x-offset_x]
```

**2. numpy**

```
data[offset_y-1:,offset_x-1:] = buffer
```

I suppose that numpy will be faster in case of large datasets.

Comment: I tried swapping range for xrange however it doesn't iterate any faster

Comment: xrange is faster and uses less memory. 42.7 ms vs 81.6 for 1000000 loops.
But if you need C-like speed, I think you need another solution.
Try numpy. Or maybe you can work without data mutation.

Comment: perhaps the benefit of xrange was drowned out by some other bottleneck but the timings came back the same (I haven't done a full formal profiling). In the end I sped the whole lot up with Cython :)

Comment: Congratulations. I've thought about something like this. Of course pure C cycle will be much faster than iterator protocol in python.